# WPF: Removing "yourself" from the parent container

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button in my user control which should be used to remove the user control from its parent container. This is the way I have coded it today.

```
private void RemoveRoleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ConfirmRoleRemoval())
    {
        Panel parentPanel = (Panel)this.Parent;
        parentPanel.Children.Remove(this);
    }
}

private bool ConfirmRoleRemoval()
{
    return MessageBox.Show("Are you sure [...]
}
```

Is it normal to do it this way in WPF?

Comment: Instead of removing you might try setting its `Visibility` property to `Collapsed`, should have the same visual effect, and won't cause too much chaos in the background.

Comment: @AviadP. have a good point ... beside that if "this" is a Usercontrol and it is a child of another Usercontrol then this.Parent will return null ... so be careful with it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it looks fine to me. As Mike Hillberg writes [in his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikehillberg/archive/2008/05/23/Of-logical-and-visual-trees-in-WPF.aspx):

> An element doesn’t actually pick its logical parent; instead, a parent “adopts” children.

Thus, it makes sense that "removing" a child is also done through the object model of the parent.

As a side note: You might want to consider throwing a "nice" exception (or even disabling the button) when the parent is not a Panel (rather than waiting for the `InvalidCastException`).